# In a windows keyboard, is right ALT treated as AltGr?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on keyboard shortcut bindings for an app.

I am trying to get it compatible across Mac and PC. I want to validate if the following below is correct.

**In PC:**

- CTRL+ALT = AltGr.
- It is the right ALT not the left ALT.
- Some keyboards have AltGr key.
- Windows keyboard differentiate left ALT and right ALT.

Comment: Interesting story, somewhat connected: *[The curious case of the disappearing Polish S](https://medium.engineering/the-curious-case-of-disappearing-polish-s-fa398313d4df)*.

Answer (score 2):

> - CTRL+ALT = AltGr.

Only in keyboard layouts which make distinction between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. On these layouts:

- Applications natively born at Windows platform make nice disctinction between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> when there is a keyboard shortcut defined. For example, when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> activates some shortcut mapping, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> still prints `€`. So in these apps, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> are **not** the same. But multi-platform apps (e.g. Eclipse IDE or some Firefox plugins) ignore this difference so <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> launches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> so you have no way to type the `€`. But this is rather a bug which hopefully developers fix, although developers using only US keyboard layout typically don't care and resist fixing this (as seen in Eclipse bug tracker). **Should you create a Windows app, test this aspect to behave correctly.**

> - It is the right ALT not the left ALT.

Yes. Applies to keyboard layouts which make distinction between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

> - Some keyboards have AltGr key.

Yes. Most of. On some netbooks, right <kbd>Alt</kbd> may be missing.

> - Windows keyboard differentiate left ALT and right ALT.

All keys are differentiated from viewpoint of the operating system, i.e. left and right <kbd>Shift</kbd>, left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd>, left and right <kbd>Win</kbd> are distinct keys although they are often interpreted in the same way – to give the user's hands comfort of pressing modifier which is reachable better. But for example some computer games allow to assign different action to left and right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key so when needed, they surely can act differently.